# How to link every instance of a word in HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I have an HTML string which I want to find every instance of a particular word and link it to a page automatically. For example, find the word 'homepage' in the HTML string and link it to the homepage of the site.

I found the following snippet of code which does the majority of the logic:

http://aidanlister.com/2004/04/highlighting-a-search-string-in-html-text/

However, it doesn't seem to consider:

1. If the word is within an HTML element's attributes (ie: img title attribute, a tag href attribute). This breaks the code.
2. If the word is already within a link, not to process it (keep it linked as it is).

The HTML String:

```
<h1>Hello, welcome to my site</h1>

<p>This is my site, if you want to go back to the homepage, just <a href="http://www.example.com">click here</a>.</p>

<a href="http://www.example.com" title="my homepage"><img src="/images/homepage.jpg" title="homepage screenshot" /></a>
```

The PHP:

```
<?

echo str_highlight($html,'homepage','wholeword|striplinks','<a href="http://www.example.com">Homepage</a>');

 ?>
```

The Function:

```
function str_highlight($text, $needle, $options = null, $highlight = null)
    {
        // Default highlighting
        if ($highlight === null) {
            $highlight = '<strong>\1</strong>';
        }

        // Select pattern to use
        if ($options & 'simple') {
            $pattern = '#(%s)#';
            $sl_pattern = '#(%s)#';
        } else {
            $pattern = '#(?!<.*?)(%s)(?![^<>]*?>)#';
            $sl_pattern = '#<a\s(?:.*?)>(%s)</a>#';
        }

        // Case sensitivity
        if (!($options & 'casesensitive')) {
            $pattern .= 'i';
            $sl_pattern .= 'i';
        }

        $needle = (array) $needle;
        foreach ($needle as $needle_s) {
            $needle_s = preg_quote($needle_s);

            // Escape needle with optional whole word check
            if ($options & 'wholeword') {
                $needle_s = '\b' . $needle_s . '\b';
            }

            // Strip links
            if ($options & 'striplinks') {
                $sl_regex = sprintf($sl_pattern, $needle_s);
                $text = preg_replace($sl_regex, '\1', $text);
            }

            $regex = sprintf($pattern, $needle_s);
            $text = preg_replace($regex, $highlight, $text);
        }

        return $text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
// Select pattern to use
    if ($options & 'simple') {
        $pattern = '#(%s)#';
        $sl_pattern = '#(%s)#';
    } else {
        $pattern = '#(?!<.*?)(%s)(?![^<>]*?>)#';
        $sl_pattern = '#<a\s(?:.*?)>(%s)</a>#';
    }
```

with

```
if ($options & 'simple') {
        $pattern = '#(%s)#';
        $sl_pattern = '#(%s)#';
    } 
    if ($options & 'html') {
        $pattern = '#(?!<.*?)(%s)(?![^<>]*?>)#';
        $sl_pattern = '#<a\s(?:.*?)>(%s)</a>#';
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
str_highlight($html,'homepage','html|wholeword|striplinks','<a href="http://www.example.com">Homepage</a>');
```

Comment: me niether. I've upped it.